# Analysis Services access configuration challenge

Tags: azure-analysis-services

Looking for access related solution that involves:
a)  Azure Analysis Services
b)  Reports in Power BI Services
c)  and restricting connection access to Azure Analysis Services from Excel, Power BI Desktop, other tools

The picture below illustrates the problem what I'm trying to solve (marked red).

1. So we want that certain Azure AD Group(s) (e.g. Salespersons) have access to Azure Analysis Services only through published Power BI Reports. So they use reports but can’t connect to Azure Analysis model with Excel, Power BI Desktop and other tools.
2. And at the same time other Azure AD Group(s) (e.g. Controllers) can use Excel and other tools to explore whole Azure Analysis Services model. They also can use reports.

I see that current Azure Analysis Services Firewall setup operates with IP Addresses.
So looks it can't be used in my case as I can identify users by AD Group(s) not IP(s).

Does anybody know is it somehow possible to solve this.
Might be in combination with some other Azure services

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNeRm.png
[link to picture]

Answer (score 0):

you can create an Azure VM, provide the user group access(allowed to use AAS from excel) on that VM and whitelist the IP of that VM in firewall of AAS server.
So anyone accessing the AAS needs to access it via the Azure VM only and not via any local IP.

As to others users, even if they have read access on AAS cube, they wont be able to access due to firewall restrictions.

Note : All the above is assuming that the POwerBi reports are in connectlive mode and not import mode.

In case if the reports are in import mode, the users need not have read access in the AAS cube but just have access on the reports